# Is application gateway a right choice in my scenario?

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway

On my on premise servers, we have two set of web apis:

1. service.xxxx.net/chartdata/data
2. service.xxxx.net/chartimage/image

We are in the process of moving our sites to azure (as two web apps). The big boss wants to keep the url structure on azure. I did some research and seems application gateway can achieve that.

However, when setting up an application gateway, I need to provide vnet and subnet information. As it is just two web apps, I don't really have a vnet.

So this makes me wonder if application gateway is indeed the right choice or not? Maybe there is something else?

Comment: Have you looked at API Management https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/api-management ?

Comment: we have two sites (west and north europe), will APIM act as a load balanccer?

Answer (score 0):

App gateway is the right solution for a single region.

You need to create Vnet for the App Gateway not for the web apps. You can check this tutorial:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/load-balance-web-traffic-with-application-gateway/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/load-balance-web-traffic-with-application-gateway/5-exercise-create-configure-application-gateway

For multiple regions, Azure Front Door is a the right one: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/frontdoor/

Comment: hi @MoonHorse, as the sites are in two region, do I need to create two app gateway (one per region)? If that is the case, how do customers choose which one to connect to?

Comment: hi @MoonHorse, isn't app front door a better choice for my scenario?

Comment: for multiple region scenarios, azure front door is a better choice. I have updated my answer